# Create a common observable which avoid multiple call

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a method that reads/writes a message.

```
fun sendMessage(message: String): Observable<MESSAGE> {
    return readMessage().doOnSubscribe {
             socket.write(message)     
    }
}
```

`readMessage()` gives back a publish subject which emits a value from a hot observable from a stream (`socket.read()`).

```
protected fun readMessage(): Observable<MESSAGE> {
    if (messageSubject == null) {
        messageSubject = PublishSubject.create()
        socket.read()
                .flatMap {
                    return@flatMap flowTransformer.runLoop(it)
                }
                .flatMap {
                    //Do some stuff
                }
                .subscribe(messageSubject)
    }
    return messageSubject
}
```

I call `sendMessage()` at a different point and multiple times in the same chain.

```
       sendMessage("Message1").flatMap { 
        sendMessage("Message2")
    }.flatMap { 
        sendMessage("Message 3")
    }.subscribe({
        //next
    }, {
        //error
    })
```

The problem is when I call `sendMessage()` I may not have yet subscribed to the publisher (so the message response is drop). I'm afraid that if I use ReplaySubject it will emit too much messages, because I use a lot of `sendMessage()`.

Some time the readObservable from the first sendMessage read all next message. And it's problem because the parse operation is CPU intensive.

How could I improve that chain?

Comment: You could make sure to have the subscription ready as soon as the first message is sent.

Comment: How could I do that ? I think I already did this by writing on the socket only when I subscribe in sendMessage() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PublishSubject with a buffer size

```
public void ReplaySubjectBufferExample()
{
  var bufferSize = 2;
  var subject = new ReplaySubject<string>(bufferSize);
  subject.OnNext("a");
  subject.OnNext("b");
  subject.OnNext("c");
  subject.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
  subject.OnNext("d");
}
```

So, in this way, you can control the number of items to be replay.
Source [ReplaySubject](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#ReplaySubject)